# How to add TextView and EditText using default AlertDialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I've been trying to add two elements in a default AlertDialog but I can't seem to make it work. Here's my code:

```
// START Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(title);
    tv.setPadding(40, 40, 40, 40);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextSize(20);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    etStr = et.getText().toString();

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(et);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Input Student ID");
    alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(tv);

    if (isError)
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_warning);
    // alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    // Setting Negative "Cancel" Button
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (isError)
                        finish();
                    else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                ChangeDeviceActivity.this,
                                MyPageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    try {
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // WindowManager$BadTokenException will be caught and the app would
        // not display the 'Force Close' message
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For now, this is only an `EditText` with a message set by `alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Input Student ID");` but I want to make this a `TextView` so I can center-justify it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(parms);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Text View title");
        tv.setPadding(40, 40, 40, 40);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(20);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        etStr = et.getText().toString();
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Input Student ID");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv1Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv1Params.bottomMargin = 5;
        layout.addView(tv1,tv1Params);
        layout.addView(et, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(layout);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        // alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Input Student ID");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(tv);

        if (isError)
            alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_warning);
        // alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        // Setting Negative "Cancel" Button
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Setting Positive "OK" Button
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (isError)
                    finish();
                else {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(ChangeDeviceActivity.this,
                      MyPageActivity.class); startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        try {
            alertDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // WindowManager$BadTokenException will be caught and the app would
            // not display the 'Force Close' message
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This works however I wanted `tv1` to be on top of the EditText so I changed `layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` to `layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` but both `tv1` and `et` is not displayed?

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate this. +1 for the edited part.

Comment: @Radon8472,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make one .xml file which include whatever view you want like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your email address :"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog1Edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress">

    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

After that in your .java file implements following code.

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.yourxmlname, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Now set the dialog's content
alert.setContentView(view);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this but I wanted to use the default alert dialog so I had to add it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `setView()` the original `TextView` holding the message gets hidden.
You need to

- create a small layout xml and put the EditText and a TextView to it
- inflate the layout
- get references of the views with `findViewById()`
- do something with the views

Comment: But with that, I could not get the android default alert dialog layout or Holo Light Theme.

Comment: Why not? The default AlertDialog theme is set outside. You just pass a view with childs instead of a plain EditText.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods above worked for me so I just created a textview, set its options and used it for the view.  It didn't need a layout or inflater.  "this" in this case was an activity.  Code in Kotlin was:

```
    val tv = TextView(this)
    with(tv) {
        text = buildInfoStr
        val dp10 = dpToPix(10)
        setPadding(dp10, dp10, dp10, dp10)
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16F)
        setTextIsSelectable(true)
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Build Info")
        .setView(tv)
        .show()
```